# Bash Script Not Returning Correct File Size

Tags: linux, bash, find, du

I have a small piece of my bash script that I would like to do the following:

- Get a list of files in the /test/f1 directory with file name "test_*.txt"
- Calculate the total size of all of these files
- Print the size to the screen

My current script is this:

```
folder="/test/f1/"
files=$(find $folder -type f -name "test_*.txt")
size=$(du -ch $files | tail -1 | cut -f 1)
echo $size
```

This works pretty well when it finds files. However, when the directory does not have any test_*.txt files, I want it to print 0 MB or 0 KB. Currently, it prints a few hundred kb.

I can verify that files (calculated in line 2) is empty when the /test/f1/ directory does not have any of these test_*.txt files. However, line 3 still seems to set size to a few hundred kb.

Why does this happen? Why isn't it showing 0 in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at this link, I think it explains your concern: https://askubuntu.com/a/317894

Comment: It's really easy to write data to stdout, but printing to "the screen" can be incredibly difficult.  (You can try writing to /dev/tty, for example, but that's not portable.)  Fortunately, it is nearly certain that you meant 'print the size to stdout', so you can avoid all the difficulties that may arise by using the abstractions provided by the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke `du` without any files, in which case it will operate on the current directory (recursively). So if you invoke `du -ch $files` and `$files` is empty, you will end up with the output of `du -ch .`

Note that [`du`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/du1.html) operates recursively on directories by default.

Comment: Adding proper quotes around `"$files"` will probably trade correct behavior for an error message when `"$files"` is empty. But you can probably add a separate case to not run `du` at all when this happens.

Comment: @tripleee That would not work if `$files` contained more than one file.